# How to remove nan and .0 in pandas when importing lists from excel

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, nan

[My excel spreadsheet]

[image: 1]

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

dictionary = pd.read_excel('dictionary.xlsx').to_dict('list')

model_name = input('model name ')

print(dictionary[model_name])
```

Output when input = model 3:

```
[11508589.0, 11508572.0, 11508541.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

Desired output:

```
[11508589, 11508572, 11508541]
```

Comment: `[x for x in lst if pd.notna(x)]`

Comment: Check out pd.DataFrame.dropna() for missing values, string formatting for dealing with comma. Or cast to int.

Answer (score 0):

use `dropna` method in pandas :

```
print(dictionary[model_name].dropna())
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas row has to have values for all columns, NaN marks no value (None).

```
# ask for column
mn = input('model name ') 
# read dataframe, select column, drop NaN
pd.read_excel('dictionary.xlsx')[mn].dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
df = pd.read_excel('dictionary.xlsx')
dictionary = df.apply(lambda s: s.dropna().astype(int).tolist()).to_dict()
```